# Android listview items show?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android app development. I write simple app to show listview and items in the list. I want when users click on the item show me row text.

**adapter**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.rowlayout,R.id.label, itemsList)
```

**rowlayout.xml**

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:layout_marginTop="4px"
        android:src="@drawable/maleki" >
    </ImageView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="50px"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:paddingLeft="100px"
        >
    </TextView>
```

I write this code into the listview click:

```
ListView myLST=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        myLST.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String itemString=((TextView) view).getText().toString();

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tourdetail.class);
                i.putExtra("countrydetail",itemString);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

but in the this line I get error:

```
String itemString=((TextView) view).getText().toString();
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: use this way String item=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label)).getText().toString();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`String itemString = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label)).getText().toString();`

or

`String itemString = myAdaptor.getItem(position)`

Answer (score 1):

Why would you cast the selected view item to TextView, which is a combination of ImageView and TextView. Check this for your solution:

```
myLST.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    TextView label= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
    String text = label.getText().toString();
    //remaining stuff
}
});
```